# Replace first 0 with two digits AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I would like to replace first 0 with two other digits in AMPscript
E.g. `0123012345`I would like this to be `98123012345`

I've tried substring/replace but it looks for all 0s in the number and does not output expected.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand your use case, but this will work if you want to trim the `0` just if the string starts with `0` and replace it with 98:

```
%%[

var @num, @repl

set @num = "0123012345"

if indexOf(@num, "0") == 1 then

  set @repl = Concat("98",Substring(@num,2,Length(@num)))

endif

]%%
number: %%=v(@num)=%%
<br>
replaced: %%=v(@repl)=%%
```

Above will output:

```
number: 0123012345
replaced: 98123012345
```

Comment: hI @zuzannamj, from my understanding the index of looks for 0 in any position of the string. Is there way to check if the string starts with 0 and set repl variable if it does?

Comment: That's exactly what I did :-) I've added a condition `if indexOf(@num, "0") == 1` which checks if the position of `0` is 1 which means that it's the first character of the string.